# How to get particles to follow a curve and follow the path angle

Tags: particles, bezier-curves

I have a particle system with an object collection of a different long line meshes. I have it following the curve ok but the instance does not change its angle as it follows the path. How can one force the angle to change? Ideally, it would be great if the instance actual curved with the animation curve. Each instance has edges along its length to bend on. I am trying to get a visual simulation of wind lines. (Using Blender 2.81)
[image]